# How to use wildcard in "when" statement in Ansible?

Tags: json, ansible

I have a created role that transfers files from the server to server. The thing is that I would like to send only specific files ending with "*tar.gz".
Right now, my role is transfering every file which contain a "tar.gz" expression. (for example tar.gz.md5 which I don't need).

How can I create a wildcard so that I can send only files ending with *tar.gz? Also I would like to have files which contain some word (like package), and ends with tar.gz: file_package-1.tar.gz
I don't need files like: file_package-1.txt, file_package-2.pdf etc.

I'm using a json file which contains a list of metadata about a file, and most important it have a path to the file. 
So I'm searching through json file in 'path' value:

```
  {
    "uid": 1009,
    "woth": false,
    "mtime": 1555410625.083113,
    "inode": 134219554,
    "isgid": false,
    "size": 1717899,
    "roth": false,
    "isuid": false,
    "isreg": true,
    "pw_name": "ansible",
    "gid": 1009,
    "ischr": false,
    "wusr": true,
    "xoth": false,
    "rusr": true,
    "nlink": 1,
    "issock": false,
    "rgrp": true,
    "gr_name": "ansible",
    "path": "/app/deploy/package_1-201810221543.tar.gz",
    "xusr": false,
    "atime": 1555410625.076113,
    "isdir": false,
    "ctime": 1555410625.083113,
    "isblk": false,
    "xgrp": false,
    "dev": 64775,
    "wgrp": false,
    "isfifo": false,
    "mode": "0640",
    "islnk": false
  },
 {
    "uid": 1009,
    "woth": false,
    "mtime": 1555410625.083113,
    "inode": 134219558,
    "isgid": false,
    "size": 79,
    "roth": false,
    "isuid": false,
    "isreg": true,
    "pw_name": "ansible",
    "gid": 1009,
    "ischr": false,
    "wusr": true,
    "xoth": false,
    "rusr": true,
    "nlink": 1,
    "issock": false,
    "rgrp": true,
    "gr_name": "ansible",
    "path": "/app/deploy/package_1-201810221543.tar.gz.md5",
    "xusr": false,
    "atime": 1555410625.083113,
    "isdir": false,
    "ctime": 1555410625.083113,
    "isblk": false,
    "xgrp": false,
    "dev": 64775,
    "wgrp": false,
    "isfifo": false,
    "mode": "0640",
    "islnk": false
  },
```

Using *.tar.gz in when statement does not find anything

```
  when: "*tar.gz' in item.path"
```

Here is my role:

```
- name: COPY FILE tar.gz
  copy:
    src: "{{ item.path }}"
    dest: "{{ HOME_PATH }}/DEPLOY/"
  with_items:
    - "{{ files }}"
  when: "tar.gz' in item.path"
```

Would be grateful for any advice

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `find` first to filter files according to certain shell/regex pattern

```
- name: FIND all tar.gz files
  find:
    paths: "[source-files-directory]"
    patterns: "[shell-or-regex-pattern]"
    use_regex: True
  register: files_to_copy
```

Visit this page for more details: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/find_module.html

2. Use `copy` without `when` condition about the filename pattern

```
- name: COPY FILE tar.gz
  copy:
    src: "{{ item.path }}"
    dest: "{{ HOME_PATH }}/DEPLOY/"
  with_items:
    - "{{ files_to_copy }}"
```

Comment: Make sense. But whenever I set any path I have an error:  "msg": "/home/gitlab-runner was skipped as it does not seem to be a valid directory or it cannot be accessed\n"

Comment: Ok, my bad. It was seraching on the remote host.

Comment: Can someone tell the answer to actual question, which says use of wildcard in when statement..?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, use [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html), something like this should work

```
- name: Copy tar.gz
  shell: cp -r *.tar.gz {{ HOME_PATH }}/DEPLOY/
  args:
    chdir: "{{ item.path }}
```